# In GBM of h2o, I set training_frame, validation_frame and nfolds at the same time. I want to know the order of training

Tags: validation, h2o, gbm

If the training_frame, validation_frame and nfolds exist at the same time. How gbm train and valid by using h2o.gbm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `validation_frame` is provided and `nfolds` >= 2 at the same time then first cross validation metrics will be computed and as a next step `gbm` will score on `validation_frame`. So for example in Flow there will be two sections:

1. Output - Validation Metrics
2. Output - Cross Validation Metrics

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get it. So firstly, gbm do the cross validation step on training set. Next, based on the finished cross validation, gbm will give the score on validaton frame.